# How do I run cinnamon in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cinnamon, desktop-environments

Is there a way to change the desktop environment of Ubuntu to cinnamon?

I only have gnome on this computer.
I am using ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-cinnamon-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: Sorry, Does not work. The boot is really slow now. How do undo what I did

Comment: I think you'll get more help if you expand your question a bit with what exactly you tried, which errors you got, etc. Olease edit your question and don't respond in the comments.